# chart.js hide x/y axis, customize

Tags: dataset, chart.js, hide, axis

i play a litle bit with chart.js and find it great.
now i want to hide the x/y axis.

[image]

i mean the 0-9 & 0 - 100 text.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```js
scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: false
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: false
          }],
        }
```